# Defining a conformal structure via null cones

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with a conformal structure $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. an equivalence class of metrics (say Lorentzian or Riemannian).

I read that the conformal structure $\mathcal{C}$ is determined by its null cones, i.e. the set of vectors $v\in T_pM\otimes\mathbb{C}$ such that $g_p(v,v)=0$ for some (and hence any) representative metric $g_p\in \mathcal{C}_p$.

Clearly if the conformal structure is known, then the null cones can be determined.

**Question 1:** How is the conformal structure determined when the null cones are known?

I think saying that a vector $v\in T_pM\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is null means saying $v$ is in the kernel of some quadratic form $Q_p$ on the tangent space. Is the conformal structure $\mathcal{C}_p$ then defined by the bilinear form $B_p$ associated to $Q_p$?

**Question 2:** How is the signature of the conformal class determined, i.e. if it is Riemannian, Lorentzian, or some other signature?

**Question 3:** How do we make sure the conformal structure varies smoothly from point to point, just by knowing its null cones?

**Question 4:** Why do we need to complexify the tangent space for this construction (or is this only necessary in special cases)?

Comment: Except in the Riemannian case, complexification isn't necessary (in the Riemannian case, the null cone is trivial, of course). See https://eudml.org/doc/135120 for the Lorentzian case. NB that one can only recover the conformal structure up to overall sign, since a bilinear form and its negative share the same null cone.